# Other than Quartz what other options or popular job scheduling tools are there?

Tags: java, tomcat, timer-jobs

Other than quartz schedular, what are other popular job services in the Java world?

Ideally something that works well with Spring.

I am assuming Tomcat can handle this type of scheduling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Spring 3.0, then the new task-scheduling namespace is pretty handy. The spring source blog has [an article on the use of the new namespace](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/05/task-scheduling-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/).

Out of curiousity, why not Quartz? It has some really neat Spring integration too.

Answer (score 0):

http://java-source.net/open-source/job-schedulers

Also there are Timers in java, and there are commercial scheduler applications. But quartz is probably the best free/open source option, and Spring already has wrappers around it.